# Можно ли разместить блок кнопок соцсетей сбоку

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте, уважаемые коллеги! Можно ли расположить блок кнопок соцсетей сбоку? То есть не под текстом, а в боковой части экрана.

Хотелось бы, чтобы кнопки работали так же, как кнопка "Вверх": при прокрутке на определенную глубину блок кнопок появлялся бы автоматически, и именно сбоку.

Можно ли это сделать и как именно?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Назначить стили на генерируемые элементы, и форматировать как угодно.

Comment: достаточно посмотреть на исходники работы кнопки "вверх" - стили для позиционирования и скрипты для отображения при скролле